# Python producer / consumer with data persistence in database?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm writing a producer / consumer to suit my needs in work.

Generally there's a producer thread which fetch some log from remote server, put it in the queue. And one or more consumer thread which read data from the queue and do some work. After that the data and the result both need to be saved (e.g. in sqlite3 db) for later analysis.

To make sure that each piece of log can be processed only once, every time before consuming the data, I have to query the database to see if it has been done. I wonder if there is a better way to accomplish this. If there are more than one consumer threads, database locking seems to be a problem.

Code relevant:

```
import Queue
import threading
import requests

out_queue = Queue.Queue()


class ProducerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Read remote log and put chunk in out_queue
            resp = requests.get("http://example.com")

            # place chunk into out queue and sleep for some time.
            self.out_queue.put(resp)
            time.sleep(10)


class ConsumerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # consume the data.
            chunk = self.out_queue.get()

            # check whether chunk has been consumed before. query the database.
            flag = query_database(chunk)
            if not flag:
                do_something_with(chunk)

                # signals to queue job is done
                self.out_queue.task_done()

                # persist the data and other info insert to the database.
                data_persist()
            else:
                print("data has been consumed before.")


def main():

    # just one producer thread.
    t = ProducerThread(out_queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

    for i in range(3):
        ct = ConsumerThread(out_queue)
        ct.setDaemon(True)
        ct.start()

    # wait on the queue until everything has been processed
    out_queue.join()

main()
```

Comment: It depends how big is your database. You can use a cache. Keeping a tuple in memory or in a parallel No-SQL database. Use a hash of the chunk in a tuple and use the `in` operator to check if it's already there. Using something like Redis can let you persist a big cache instead. In this case you would just ask for `Redis.get(chunk)`, if the result is not `None` you have already in the database.

Comment: or any No-SQL that fits the task. Maybe memcached also in this case.

Comment: @tunedconsulting Hmm... Redis is what I'm digging into. But I'm still a little puzzled about the relationship between Redis and the database file on disk. So the consumer just first save the results in Redis cache, after some time I'll save the cache into the database? Also about the multithread problem, should the 'check-if-already' process happen at the producer side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logs read remote server are not duplicated/repeated, then there is no  need to check whether the logs are processed for multiple times, as [Queue class implements all the required locking semantics](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and thus Queue.get() ensures a specific item could only be got by one ConsumerThread.

If the logs could be duplicated (I guess not), then you should do the checking in ProducerThread (before adding the logs to the queue), rather than the do checking in ConsumerThread. In this way, you don't need to consider locking.

**update based on @dofine's confirmation on my understanding about the requirement in below comments**:

For points #2 and #3, you may need a **lightweight persistent** queue such as FifoDiskQueue in [queuelib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/queuelib). To be honest, I didn't use this lib before but I think it should work for you. Please check out the lib.

For point #1, I guess you can achieve it by using whatever a (non-memory) database, in combination with another queue of FifoDiskQueue:

- The 2nd queue serves the purpose of re-queueing a log immediately if it fails to be processed by one consumer thread. Please see my first comment below for the idea
- there is a single table in the db. The  producer thread always adds new records to it, but never updates any records; and the consumer thread only updates those records it has picked from the queue
- with above logic, you should never needs a lock the table
- on application startup (prior to starting the consumers), you may have the producer query the db for those logs that are "lost" in track due to application's unexpected termination

*this update is typed in mobile SO, so it is kind of inconvenient to extend it. If needed, I will update again when I get a chance*

Comment: Thanks! Well the data I need from the log could be duplicated, e.g. the user could login several times a day, but I only need push a msg to him once per day. So I've to do the checking in Producer then, check where this user has received my push-msg.

Comment: So, as I suggested above, a simple check by using dict in ProducerThread could meet your need. However, you could "never" determine whether the user has received your push-msg (unless there is a response). Instead, what you can achieve is to know whether you have successfully sent out the message - one quick idea is to establish another queue to store chunks that fail to be processed by those ConsumerThread, and have those ConsumerThread to be producers of this new queue and have the ProducerThread to be the single consumer (which re-adds the chunks back to the first queue).

Comment: The send message part is provided by another API call, which would send back a response. So that shouldn't be a problem. But forgive me for being a newbie when it comes to database and multithread. :) It's quite easy to use a dict to do the check. How about the save-to-db part? When should I do that? If I understand right, I can use a dict(or whatever, redis) as a 'cache' for the actual database?

Comment: Let's go back to your requirement firstly. By rereading your question and comments, there looks like two points in the requirement - 1)  a log (that could be duplicated) is only processed for one time; and 2) a log must be processed (eventually). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: and 3) the log processing order is FIFO?